# Can't send data between to view controllers Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have got a tabbed project in my Xcode.But my `Entry Point` is a separate view controller that is not connected to tabs.So when user clicks `Login` button i send value of input to one of view controllers in tabbed part of my project.I have a segue between separated VC and VC that I send data to.Here is my code In part where I send the data

```
protocol SendDel {
    func userDidEnterData(data: String)
}

LogInViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate:SendDel!=nil
    @IBAction func SendB(_ sender: Any) {
        if(delegate != nil){
            if(self.Usn != nil){
                let data = self.Usn.text
                self.delegate?.userDidEnterData(data: data!)
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

And here is code in part where I receive data

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController,SendDel {

  func userDidEnterData(data: String) {
    UsernameLabel.text="\(data)"
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier ==  "First"){
        let sendingVc=segue.destination as! LogInViewController
        sendingVc.delegate = self
    }
   }
 }
```

But unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: Do you set identifier in your storyboard ?

Comment: Yes I do and it's name is `First` @AdrianBobrowski

Comment: You can do alternative for this. You can save your data in NSUserDefaults or make a Global dictionary or array in which you can store your data.

Comment: Can you set brekpoint in line `self.delegate?.userDidEnterData(data: data!)` and check if your function in delegate is colled

Comment: Have you chck whther you delegate is nil or not??

Comment: @GouravJoshi thank you!I used NSUserDefaults and it worked.It's is not bad to use them all over my project,is It?

Comment: Yes, if it is really difficult to debug the issue then without wasting your efforts you can go to this approach.

Comment: Although NSUserDefaults is not the correct answer please use the "Answer" field to state how you fixed this question. Please do not place answers in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you setting the delegate property from `FirstViewController` and then when you present the `LogInViewController` you have write the code `var delegate:SendDel!=nil` which makes delegate `nil` every time you tapped the button.

So try below code :

```
 var delegate: SendDel?
```

Hope it works for you.